# What is the meaning of "evaluate to something"

Tags: meaning

I was reading one of the questions in stackoverflow and I saw [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19224/9896037).

At the beginning of the answer I saw this sentence at the first line :

> Expression: Something which **evaluates to a value**. Example: 1+2/x

My problem is, what does the sentence mean when it says "evaluate to something" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we evaluate an expression we determine the value it has under certain circumstances. If we want to evaluate 1 + 2/x we would usually know the value of x. Suppose in fact the value of x is 0.5 then the expression evaluates to 5.

Outside of the mathematical context *evaluate* has a similar meaning but slightly different. You might say *He evaluated the discussion highly* without any suggestion that he gave it a numerical value.